# How to use a part of struct in ShouldBindJSON()?

Tags: go, struct

I'm using Go 1.17 with Gin. Here is my struct:

```
package model

type Movie struct {
    ID         string `json:"id"`
    Year       uint16 `json:"year" binding:"required,lt=3000"`
    RentNumber uint32 `json:"rent_number" db:"rent_number" binding:"required,lt=4294967290"`
    Title      string `json:"title" binding:"required,max=255"`
    Author     string `json:"author" binding:"required,max=80"`
    Editor     string `json:"editor" binding:"required,max=125"`
    Index      string `json:"index" binding:"required,max=125"`
    Bib        string `json:"bib" binding:"required,max=20"`
    Ref        string `json:"ref" binding:"required,max=20"`
    Cat1       string `json:"cat_1" db:"cat_1" binding:"required,max=20"`
    Cat2       string `json:"cat_2" db:"cat_2" binding:"required,max=10"`
}
```

I have a problem to use this struct in a certain handler. In this handler I just need to use 2 properties (Title and Year) from my movie struct. If I'm doing something like this:

```
func (h *Handler) myHandler(c *gin.Context) {
    var movie model.Movie

    if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&movie); err != nil {
        c.Error(err)
        c.Abort()
        return
    }
    ...
```

It will not working because on this web service I'll send only 2 properties and I'll get the required errors from the binding tags:

```
{
    "title": My title",
    "year": 2017
}
```

So I want to know what is the "go way" to handle this ? I can see 3 solutions.

- Use the movie struct and ignoring all fields except `Title` and`Year`, but how I can do that ?
- Create a specific struct with just the needed fields. In this case I'll not place this struct in the model package but in my movie api package

  ```
   type StructForTheSpecialHandler struct {
      Year       uint16 `json:"year" binding:"required,lt=3000"`
      Title      string `json:"title" binding:"required,max=255"`
   }
  ```
- Create the struct directly in my handler like this:

  ```
  func (h *Handler) myHandler(c *gin.Context) {
     var tmp struct {
         Year  uint16 `json:"year" binding:"required,lt=3000"`
         Title string `json:"title" binding:"required,max=255"`
     }

     if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&tmp); err != nil {
         c.Error(err)
         c.Abort()
         return
     }
     ...
  ```

Can you tell me if you have a better solution or tell me what is the right way between my 3 solutions?

Comment: maybe ",omitempty" works for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just unmarshal it directly (bypassing the validation completely):

```
err := json.NewDecoder(c.Request.Body).Decode(&movie)
```

Or you could try to embed those properties in the struct:

```
type EmbeddedMovieFields struct {
   Year  uint16 `json:"year" binding:"required,lt=3000"`
   Title string `json:"title" binding:"required,max=255"`
}

type Movie struct {
    EmbeddedMovieFields
    ID         string `json:"id"`
    RentNumber uint32 `json:"rent_number" db:"rent_number" binding:"required,lt=4294967290"`
    Author     string `json:"author" binding:"required,max=80"`
    Editor     string `json:"editor" binding:"required,max=125"`
    Index      string `json:"index" binding:"required,max=125"`
    Bib        string `json:"bib" binding:"required,max=20"`
    Ref        string `json:"ref" binding:"required,max=20"`
    Cat1       string `json:"cat_1" db:"cat_1" binding:"required,max=20"`
    Cat2       string `json:"cat_2" db:"cat_2" binding:"required,max=10"`
}

var movie model.EmbeddedMovieFields

if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&movie); err != nil {
    c.Error(err)
    c.Abort()
    return
}
```